# What is the best method of getting the key of the last added array item in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, key

Is there a better way to do the following:

```
$array = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');
// do a bunch of other stuff, probably a loop
$array[] = 'test6';
end($array);
echo key($array); // gives me 6
```

This will give the key of the most recently add array element.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also do:

```
$end = end(array_keys($array));
```

But I think your way makes it clear what you want to do, so you could whip something up like:

```
function array_last_key($array) {
    end($array);
    return key($array);
}
```

That's about it.

Comment: I'd just like to throw out there that this is my biggest complaint with PHP.  Negative array indices are definitely a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special function for this in PHP, so I think your way is the most efficent way of doing this. For readability you might want to put it in a function called something like array_last_key().

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that your array won't have any non-numerical keys and that you aren't going to be deleting any keys, then the last element added to your array's key will be

```
$last_added = count($array)-1;
```

If you really need to keep track of the latest added key, you may want to come up with a scheme to come up with your own keys that are guaranteed to be unique. this way you'll always have the latest added key since you generated it.

```
$array = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');
// do a bunch of other stuff, probably a loop
$new_key = generate_key();
$array[$new_key] = 'test6';
echo $new_key; // gives me blahblahfoobar123
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put no. Both end and key are Big O(1) time.  Any other way slows your code down and adds complexity.

Comment: What do you mean by "Big O(1) time"?

Comment: The time stays the same, no matter how big your array gets