# Checking if a key is the last element in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I check if this key is the last element in an array?

```
$array = array("a","b","c");
```

The value "c" would have the key 2. Is there some code like this `is_end(2)` which returns true or false depending if they key is the last of the array? Is there some kind of `while()` statement I can use?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892848/return-last-numeric-key-not-value-of-an-array ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216030/what-is-the-best-method-of-getting-the-key-of-the-last-added-array-item-in-php

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use [end()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) and [key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) to get the key at the end of the array.

```
end($array);
$lastKey = key($array);
```

Comment: maybe you mean something like: end($array);$lastKey = key($array);
but you cant do it all in just 1 sentence.....

Comment: does this method have any advantages over using `count($array)-1`?

Comment: @andyface - the advantage is that you can use this method with associative arrays instead of just numeric based keys (ie: ($array['mykey'] - 1) = undefined)

Comment: no better method with associative arrays? this seems clunky?

Comment: For the sake of completeness: count() returns the number of items not valid Keys. If you have string keys or other key orders than 0,1,2,3,.. 
$array[ count($array)-1 ] will not work.

Answer (score 5):

You can [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the array values:

```
$last_index = count($array) - 1;
```

But this won't work with associative arrays.

Comment: this is the method I normally use? never sure if it's the best, but the accepted answer seems like it would cause issues/confusion if using with a foreach loop for instance. anyone got any insight?

Comment: `foreach` and `end` both modify the internal array pointer (to the "current" element), so using both constructs at the same time messes things up.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: count() returns the number of items not valid Keys. If you have string keys or other key orders than 0,1,2,3,.. $array[ count($array)-1 ] will not work either.

Answer (score 1):

```
$is_2_lastone = array_pop(array_keys($array)) === 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't use an [associative array](http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art31316.asp), you could just check the length of the array, using [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). It will return `1+last index in array`

Comment: For the sake of completeness: count() returns the number of items not valid Keys. If you have string keys or other key orders than 0,1,2,3,.. $array[ count($array)-1 ] will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 7 >= 7.3.0 or PHP 8 you can use [array_key_last()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php)

`$last_key = array_last_key( $arr );`